# Replacing heat only thermostat

Tags: wiring, thermostat-c-wire, boiler, heat

I have a two wire standard thermostat, RH & W
It is heat only for my downstairs area and has a zone valve.
To my boiler the RH wire goes up to the zone valve and the W wire is going to R location on the transformer that supplies 28v. I’m trying to hook up a wifi thermostat.

The wiring behind my stat has an extra wire that’s not being used so I can use it as the control wire but I’m lost on how to connect it since the control wire should be the one connected to 28v but I have that W wire that’s already there from the old stat getting the 28v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through some steps with ecobee they confirmed that the ecobee 4 gets its power from the RC side and it has an internal jumper so although I’m using it for heat only I wired the Rh which has constantly 24-28v to the Rc side. My C wire and W wire which don’t have current on them and all systems a go.

Answer (score 2):

Think of your thermostat as a switch.  The furnace provides ~24VAC on terminal **R** (or Rc or Rh in the case of a cool-only/heat-only).  When the thermostat decides to ask the furnace for something, it shorts (returns) that voltage on the correct terminal, which in your case is **W** for heat (**Y** for cool, **G** for circ, etc.)

A smart thermostat needs straight AC power to run its brains, completely separate from the switching duties.  That is provided by adding a **C** wire to complete the circuit (R/Rh/Rc being the "line" feed).  You can use your unused 3rd wire for that.  Simply connect your unused wire to a suitable ground reference at the furnace (nearly every furnace control board provides a **C** terminal for that - otherwise you can use the grounded terminal on the secondary of the furnace transformer).  Connect the other end to the **C** terminal on your thermostat and you're done.

I am not sure what you mean by control wire - do you perhaps mean "Common"?  If so, that is the **C** I explained above.  In the general sense, they're all control wires.

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant the common wire. Anyhow I tried connecting that 3rd wire commmon wire to the negative/ground on the transformer and the thermostat won’t come on. I have two Honeywell zone valves. One for upstairs and the other for downstairs. Zone upstairs has a wifi stat as well that runs upstairs heat and separate central air. Down here it’s just heat.

Comment: I have a Weil McLain boiler transformer has Y, W, C, G & R terminals.  C terminal is ground R is 28v. 
My W wire is the one carrying power 28v from the R terminal on the transformer. 

The RH wire runs to the Honeywell zone valve then two wires come back down from the zone valve one going to the transformer R terminal and another wire going to G terminal.